# How do I instruct artisan to save model to specific directory?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5. I have created a `/Models` directory under the `/App` directory, but when generating the models using Artisan it's storing them under the `App` directory.

I have searched the documentation to try and find how to specify a different path name, but to no avail:

```
php artisan make:model TestModel
```

How do I instruct `artisan` to save the model to specific directory?

Comment: Yes. There's 17 models in total, with various relationships, and the possibility of the models growing as more features are implemented. I do not want them under the `/app` directory. It's not the place for them anyway.

Comment: My point is, won't it be fairly trivial to move them yourself?

Comment: Oh, yeah sure that's what I've ended up doing but I'd still like to know if a solution exists as it's much quicker for my workflow to be able to use the generators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to specify the path when generating a model, you can use the [Laravel Generators Package](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators). You can then specify the location using the `--path` option like so:

```
php artisan generate:model TestModel --path=my/custom/location
```

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5. That returns an error: `exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace.' in /Users/me/wwwl/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:501
`

Comment: And those are L4 generators not L5.

Comment: There's version 3 of the generators which is for L5.

Comment: Just include `"way/generators": "~3.0"` in `composer.json`. The instructions are [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#laravel-50-and-above).

Comment: I think it should be
`generate:model [--path="..."] [--templatePath="..."] modelName` the path before the model name.

Comment: I am getting Error `"--path" option does not exist`. using laravel 5.2

Comment: Getting the same error "--path" option does not exists.

Answer (score 115):

Create a Models directory or whatever your want to named it, put it in inside app directory. The Directory structure should look like

```
laravel-project
     /app
        /Console
        /Events
        /Exceptions
        /Http
        /Jobs
        /Listeners
        /Provider
       /Models
```

Then You just need to type artisan command for creating models inside Models directory

```
php artisan make:model Models/ModelName
```

After Creating Models your namespace inside model classes will be

```
namespace app-name\Models\ModelName
```

You can access this model in inside your controller

```
use app-name\Models\ModelName
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, this works perfectly. And this even creates the Models subdirectory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Warning: Does not work in 5.2 with /App in your path. Data/Models/App/Phase will be put in Data/Models/ but with namespace Data/Models/App/Phase in file.

Comment: If not working. double check it's backward Slash (/) not forward.

Answer (score 26):

## In Laravel 5.4 or later

You can create as below

```
 > php artisan make:model "Models\userModel"
```

here **Models** is directory name and **userModel** is model name

> Use " (double quotes) or ' (single quotes) to create model

Comment: Can confirm this also works for making commands such as `php artisan make:command "Foo\Bar\MyCommand"`. This will create the file in `app/Console/Commands/Foo/Bar/MyCommand.php`.

Answer (score 23):

## For those using Laravel >= 5.2

It is possible to generate a model in a subdirectory using built-in Artisan  generators by "escaping" the backslashes in the FQN, like so:

### Laravel 5.2

```
php artisan model:make App\\Models\\Foo
```

### Laravel 5.3

```
php artisan make:model App\\Models\\Foo
```

(the difference between 5.2 and 5.3 pointed out by [@Khaled Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5444599/khaled-rahman), thanks!)

Commands above would create `Foo.php` file in the app/Models directory and update the namespace accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: **In laravel 5.3** :  `php artisan make:model  App\\Models\\Foo`

Comment: **In laravel 5.4:** `php artisan make:model Models/Foo`. It places the file under `Models` directory with appropriate namespace.

Comment: On linux (Laravel 5.3):
php artisan model:make Models/Foo

Answer (score 9):

You can override the default Laravel command with this console class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ModelMakeCommand;

class ModelMake extends ModelMakeCommand
{
    protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace.'\\Models';
    }
}
```

The next time you make a model

> `php artisan make:model Example`

your class will be placed in

> `App\Models\Example.php`

Edit: Laravel 8 natively support this. I copied this snippet from somewhere, I just can't remember where to credit.

Comment: I tried this same method on Laravel 6 as well and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this (for Laravel 5.3+):

```
php artisan make:model your_path/model_name
```

If you don't specify a path it will use main 'app' folder as root. So you can navigate from there.

Models/Folder1/MyModel means app->Models->Folder1->MyModel.php

Answer (score 0):

This works for actual Laravel version, `5.6.28`, on Windows 7

```
php artisan make:model App\Models\NewModel
```

> Note: *Do not use double escapes (`'\\'`)*

This generate the file `App\Models\NewModel.php` as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NewModel extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Laravel 8+** with default Models directory it can be achieved like bellow.

**`php artisan make:model App\Modules\ModuleName\Models\ModelName`**

It generates model file in directory

`app/Modules/ModuleName/Models/ModelName.php`

```
<?php
    namespace App\Modules\ModuleName\Models;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class ModelName extends Model {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `composer.json` file if it is not defined.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            //...
        }
```

Then in your terminal do;
`php artisan make:model Models/your_path/model_name`

Answer (score -1):

Controller path (ApI/Admin)

Model path(Model/Admin)

php artisan make:controller API/Admin/PlanController  --model=Model/Admin/Plan --resource