# How do you reference a model in a laravel controller?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm finding the distinction between "Controller" and "Model" in laravel 5.2 to be very blurry.

I use artisan to create a RESTful controller, and in the store method, I try to create a new object.

```
// store in the database
$car = new App\Models\CarModel;
```

Then I get the error as follows:

```
Class 'carfreak\Http\Controllers\App\Models\CarModel' not found
```

So it all seems to come down to the namespace of the controller, but I don't understand it.

The name space describes the controller, right? 
So why is my reference the model, being built on the controllers path? It shouldn't have anything to do with it... right?

EDIT: After trying various suggestions, I've concluded there are three things to look at:

1. Each class has a namespace set, correctly describing the folder where the class is located
2. In the controller, have the statement "Use app\models\CarModel"
3. refer to the model in the controller.

Each seems to be correct, but I still get the error that it cannot find the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here it is. I solved it by asking myself this question: If I'm having so much trouble namespacing, referencing and organising my models, then maybe I can get artisan to do it for me.

The post that got me thinking differently was Mansoor Akhtar's advice here: [How do I instruct artisan to save model to specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225163/how-do-i-instruct-artisan-to-save-model-to-specific-directory)

1. Get artisan to make the model in the right place first time. 
   `php artisan make:model Models/CarModel`
2. In the Controller, reference the model correctly
   `use name-of-app\Models\CarModel;`
3. There may or may not be cache flushing involved in my problem. I was eventially restarting my XAMPP after every change to ensure no caching was involved. I also tried
   `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 3):

This is a namespace problem in php.

You just use like this.

```
$car = new \App\Models\CarModel;
```

or

```
use App\Models\CarModel;
....    
class {
    $car = new CarModel;
}
```

Comment: You mean in my controller class? It doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, you can reference laravel source code...

Answer (score 1):

First of all check name space in Model file , Define name space in model file

```
namespace App\Http\Models;
```

And then use

```
use App\Http\Models\CarModel;
```

Comment: ok, except that my structure is app\models rather than apps\http\models. Doesn't help though :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a `use` statement to the top of your class.

Try:

```
use carfreak\Models\CarModel;

class ...
```

This assumes that your model is in the `carfreak\Models` namespace, and in a `Models` folder within your `App` / `carfreak` folder, otherwise you'll just need `use carfreak\CarModel;`.

Comment: Done that. Doesn;t change anything

Comment: What's the namespace of your controller?

Comment: namespace carfreak\Http\Controllers;

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the new namespace, try it with those `use` statements and see if that helps.

Comment: Yep, tried that. No go. I've tried all sort of permutations, but I keep getting the error `Class 'app\Models\CarModel' not found`. It almost makes me think that I am supposed to register my model somewhere.

Comment: Have you run `php composer update`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118610/discussion-between-maxcot-and-daniel-waghorn).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have just ran the artisan command to create the model and you didn't move the `CarModel` file to Models folder. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

So in your controller add this before class declaration:

```
use carfreak\CarModel;
```

Then anywhere in your controller you can access the model like this:

```
$car = new CarModel;
```